# how to check which tables are loaded into the memory?

Tags: hana

I have loaded two tables from the database into the memory and did a join query. (At this time the used memory was 40 GB). After that I unloaded both the tables from the memory but still the used memory was showing 10 GB even after refreshing many times. To ensure that no other tables are loaded I unloaded all the tables. But still it shows the same amount.

1. Could any one tell what causes this?
2. Can we see which tables are loaded into the memory in HANA?

Answer (score 1):

HANA can load/unload data per column and table (table partition for partitioned tables). You can find out which columns of which table (table partition) are loaded using system view M_CS_ALL_COLUMNS, column LOADED.

But you have to consider, that HANA needs memory for other purposes as well: system tables/views, statistics, caches and much more. Those memory areas will not be released by an unload.
There are also some SQL statements available in SAP Note 1969700 to analyze memory consumption by tables and other consumers.